# My Django form renders always with type='hidden'

Tags: python, django

I did exactly with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/ , but after the html page rendered, the form is hidden. And the source code from html is as following:

```
<form action = "/blogcore/register/" method = "post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='0aFX5lRZm4qdP5CfHoZbqSohGEipkWN4' /> 
<input type = "submit" value = "Next" />
```

How can I do to make the form display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is not hidden. Only the csrf token is hidden, which is correct.